# Whitespace in returned query with Python and py-postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm using the [py-postgresql](http://python.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/1.1/driver.html#queries) driver. Whenever I do a `SELECT` it works correctly, but I get the full width of the column returned, with whitespace. So if I have a field of `character(25)` which holds "Name", and do:

```
SELECT name WHERE name = 'Name'
```

I get

```
"Name                     " << "Name" followed by 21 spaces
```

instead of just `Name`

Example Code that I've run straight from IDLE

```
db = posgresql.driver.connect(user     = [USERNAME],
                              password = [PASSWORD],
                              host     = [HOST],
                              port     = [PORT]
)

db.query("SELECT [FIELD] FROM [TABLE] WHERE [TRUE]")
```

No issues with it returning, and yes, I know how to strip the whitespace off the end, but it may need to be there, so I'm really trying to figure out how to get things to return without excess whitespace.

Comment: Can you change column type to `varchar`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your column is probably defined as a `CHAR(n)` type, and the database has to honor that, so it is adding spaces at the end. You should switch your column type to `VARCHAR(n)`, which is a variable length field with maximum length of `n`, and there will be no more trailing spaces.

Comment: That's it. I had misunderstood something I had read before, which I thought had said varchar and character are the same. Actually said varchar and varying are the same.

Comment: It's all in the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html